# ElasticSearch should with nested and bool must_not exists

Tags: elasticsearch

With the following mapping:

```
"categories": {
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
      "category": {
          "type": "integer"
      },
      "score": {
          "type": "float"
      }
  }
},
```

I want to use the `categories` field to return documents that either:

- have a score above a threshold in a given category, or
- do not have the categories field

This is my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "categories",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "categories.category": [
                        <id>
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "categories.score": {
                        "gte": 0.5
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "categories"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

It correctly returns documents both with and without the categories field, and orders the results so the ones I want are first, but it doesn't filter the results having score below the 0.5 threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question.

That is because `categories` is not exactly a field from the elasticsearch point of view[a field on which inverted index is created and used for querying/searching] but `categories.category` and `categories.score` is.

As a result `categories` being not found in any document, which is actually true for all the documents, you observe the result what you see.

Modify the query to the below and you'd see your use-case working correctly.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "categories",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "categories.category": [
                        "100"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "categories.score": {
                        "gte": 0.5
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [                        <----- Note this
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "categories",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "exists": {
                            "field": "categories.category"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "exists": {
                            "field": "categories.score"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ah, great - and thanks for the explanation, that really helps